# How to read information from file to vector<bool>?

Tags: c++, vector, bit

I want to use `vector<bool>` to store binary data (0/1).

I couldn't find a proper way to read from a file filled with binary data to the vector so that each cell will contain 1 bit.

More over, is there a way to approach a range of values from the vector?
For example, to write bits 1-20 in a single command.

Answer (score 2):

This answers your direct question.

```
std::vector<bool> whole_data;
std::ifstream file("myfile", std::ios::binary);
char data;
while (file.read(&data, 1))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i++)
    {
        whole_data.push_back(((data >> i) & 1) != 0);
    }
}
```

However, consider whether you need to read the whole file into memory at once (what if it's large?). Also I'm not making any comment whether `vector<bool>` is the best data structure to use here. I don't know what you are going to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee that `vector<bool>` is an actual vector of bits -- implementations are allowed to specialize `vector<>` for it, but not required to. And it's debatable if it's a performance improvement at all, there's a reason why `bool` on most platforms are word aliases (same size as the OS word size).

You could use [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html), which has these guarantees. Or any number of other bitset implementations.

As to how to add values, read the manual of whatever you choose to use. `vector<>` uses `push_back`, `dynamic_bitset` uses `append`, etc.

Comment: He said that he wants each cell to contain 1 bit, not necessarily that it is a vector of bits, if you know what I mean, so I'm giving him the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: It's not about having the benefit of the doubt, it's about guarantees. `vector<bool>` offers no such guarantees.

Comment: Each element of the vector *will* contain 1 bit of data from the file. That doesn't necessarily mean it's a bit vector.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! Eventually I decided to use dynamic bitset .